# Creating a multi-level bullet list with Word.Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I need to create a multi-level bullet list via `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and I am currently struggling with its (horrible) API (again).

I've just created the following example (not dynamic yet, just for demonstration purposes) in a VSTO document-level project for Microsoft Office Word 2010 in the programming language C#:

```cs
Word.Paragraph paragraph = null;
Word.Range range = this.Content;
paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Item 1";
paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault(Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior);
// ATTENTION: We have to outdent the paragraph AFTER its list format has been set, otherwise this has no effect.
// Without this, the the indent of "Item 2" differs from the indent of "Item 1".
paragraph.Outdent();

paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Item 1.1";
// ATTENTION: We have to indent the paragraph AFTER its text has been set, otherwise this has no effect.
paragraph.Indent();
paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Item 1.2";
paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Item 2";
paragraph.Outdent();
```

The code does exactly what I want (after a lot of try and error!), but it's horrible in my opinion. The format has to be applied at a VERY specific point and I have to manually indent and outdent the created paragraphs.

So my question is: **Does a better approach exist to create a multi-level bullet list via `Word.Interop`, e.g. via shorthand methods that I haven't discovered yet?**

My goal is to create a multi-level list from XML data (more specific a `CustomXMLNode` object)

Two other questions related to bullet lists exist on Stack Overflow, but both do not help me (the source code above is one answer to the second question):

- [Bullet points in Word with c# Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508286/bullet-points-in-word-with-c-sharp-interop)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768414/ms-word-list-with-sub-lists

**EDIT (2013-08-08):**

I've just hacked something together that outputs two arrays as a bullet list with two levels (the array with the sub-items is used for each root-item, to keep it simple). By introducing recursion, one would be able to create a bullet list with infinite levels (theoretically). But the problem remains, the code is a mess...

```cs
string[] rootItems = new string[]
{
    "Root Item A", "Root Item B", "Root Item C"
};

string[] subItems = new string[]
{
    "Subitem A", "Subitem B"
};

Word.Paragraph paragraph = null;
Word.Range range = this.Content;
bool appliedListFormat = false;
bool indented = false;

for (int i = 0; i < rootItems.Length; ++i)
{
    paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
    paragraph.Range.Text = rootItems[i];

    if (!appliedListFormat)
    {
        paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault(Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior);
        appliedListFormat = true;
    }

    paragraph.Outdent();
    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

    for (int j = 0; j < subItems.Length; ++j)
    {
        paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
        paragraph.Range.Text = subItems[j];

        if (!indented)
        {
            paragraph.Indent();
            indented = true;
        }

        paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
    }

    indented = false;
}

// Delete the last paragraph, since otherwise the list ends with an empty sub-item.
paragraph.Range.Delete();
```

**EDIT (2013-08-12):**

Last friday I thought I have achieved what I wanted to, but this morning I noticed, that my solution only works if the insertion point is at the end of the document. I've created the following simple example to demonstrate the (erroneous) behavior. To conclude my problem: I am able to create multi-level bullet lists at the end of the document **only**. As soon as I change the current selection (e.g. to the start of the document), the list is destroyed. As far as I can see, this is related to the (automatic or non-automatic) extension of the `Range` objects. I've tried a lot so far (I'm almost losing it), but it's all cargo-cult to me. The only thing I want to do is to insert one element after another (is it impossible to create a content control **inside** a paragraph, so that the text of the paragraph is followed by the content control?) **and** to to that in any `Range` of a `Document`. I will create a Gist on GitHub with my actual `CustomXMLPart` binding class this evening. Eventually someone can help me to fix that bothersome problem.

```cs
private void buttonTestStatic_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Word.Range range = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection.Range;
    Word.ListGallery listGallery = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ListGalleries[Word.WdListGalleryType.wdBulletGallery];
    Word.Paragraph paragraph = null;
    Word.ListFormat listFormat = null;

    // TODO At the end of the document, the ranges are automatically expanded and inbetween not?

    paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
    listFormat = paragraph.Range.ListFormat;
    paragraph.Range.Text = "Root Item A";
    this.ApplyListTemplate(listGallery, listFormat, 1);
    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

    paragraph = paragraph.Range.Paragraphs.Add();
    listFormat = paragraph.Range.ListFormat;
    paragraph.Range.Text = "Child Item A.1";
    this.ApplyListTemplate(listGallery, listFormat, 2);
    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

    paragraph = paragraph.Range.Paragraphs.Add();
    listFormat = paragraph.Range.ListFormat;
    paragraph.Range.Text = "Child Item A.2";
    this.ApplyListTemplate(listGallery, listFormat, 2);
    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

    paragraph = paragraph.Range.Paragraphs.Add();
    listFormat = paragraph.Range.ListFormat;
    paragraph.Range.Text = "Root Item B";
    this.ApplyListTemplate(listGallery, listFormat, 1);
    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
}

private void ApplyListTemplate(Word.ListGallery listGallery, Word.ListFormat listFormat, int level = 1)
{
    listFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(
        listGallery.ListTemplates[level],
        ContinuePreviousList: true,
        ApplyTo: Word.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToSelection,
        DefaultListBehavior: Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior,
        ApplyLevel: level);
}
```

**EDIT (2013-08-12):** I've set up a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/FlorianWolters/CSharp-WordInterop-Temp) which demonstrates my problem with the `Word.Range` objects. The `OnClickButton` method in the file `Ribbon.cs` invokes my custom mapper class. The comments there describe the problem. I **know** that my problems are related to the argument `Word.Range` object reference, but all other solutions I tried (e.g. modifying the range inside of the class) failed even harder. The best solution I've achieved so far, is to specify the `Document.Content` range as the argument for the `MapToCustomControlsIn` method. This inserts a nicely formatted multi-level bullet list (with custom XML parts bound to content controls) to the *end* of the document. What I want is to insert that list *at a custom posiztion* into the document (e.g. the current selection via `Word.Selection.Range`).

Comment: The most common ways to apply bullet list or numbered list is with methods which you have already (partially) recognised: `ApplyBulletDefault`or `ApplyListTemplate`. The only think I see that you could improve is the reference to the range. You don't need to loop. If you have your text already placed in the document you can `ApplyBulletDefault` to that range, like for selection: `Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault`. So, is there anything I could help you with?

Comment: @KazJaw, yes, you can. :D See my last edit for further information.

Comment: I didn't have an opportunity to run your VSTO project but I check the last snippet of code in VS setting appropriate references. And it works for selected range quite ok except first run- that time first indent doesn't look as expected. But second run works ok. But I don't know what is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Florian Wolters example almost there, but the first child item numbering always not correct when I tried.

Someone gave me inspiration by suggesting using Macro and VBA script then convert to C#.

Below is the sample code tested works at my side. Hope it helps.

```js
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;

namespace OfficeUtility
{
    public class NumberListGenerate
    {
        public void GenerateList()
        {
            Application app = null;
            Document doc = null;
            string filePath = "c:\\output.docx";
            string pdfPath = "c:\\export.pdf";

            try
            {
                app = new Application();
                app.Visible = false;    // Open Microsoft Office in background
                doc = app.Documents.Open(filePath, Missing.Value, false);

                Range range = doc.Range();
                string search = "$list";
 
                // Find in document to generate list
                while (range.Find.Execute(search))
                {
                    ListGallery listGallery = 
                        app.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery];

                    // Select found location
                    range.Select();

                    // Apply multi level list
                    app.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(
                        listGallery.ListTemplates[1],
                        ContinuePreviousList: false,
                        ApplyTo: WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList, 
                        DefaultListBehavior: WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior);

                    // First level
                    app.Selection.TypeText("Root Item A");  // Set text to key in
                    app.Selection.TypeParagraph();  // Simulate typing in MS Word

                    // Go to 2nd level
                    app.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent();
                    app.Selection.TypeText("Child Item A.1");
                    app.Selection.TypeParagraph();
                    app.Selection.TypeText("Child Item A.2");
                    app.Selection.TypeParagraph();

                    // Back to 1st level
                    app.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListOutdent(); 
                    app.Selection.TypeText("Root Item B");
                    app.Selection.TypeParagraph();

                    // Go to 2nd level
                    app.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent();
                    app.Selection.TypeText("Child Item B.1");
                    app.Selection.TypeParagraph();
                    app.Selection.TypeText("Child Item B.2");
                    app.Selection.TypeParagraph();

                    // Delete empty item generated by app.Selection.TypeParagraph();
                    app.Selection.TypeBackspace();
                }

                // Save document
                doc.Save();

                // Export to pdf 
                doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfPath, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);                   
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                LogError(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (doc != null)
                {
                    // Need to close the document to prevent deadlock
                    doc.Close(false);
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
                }

                if (app != null)
                {
                    app.Quit();
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the DefaultList Behavior to WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior is key here. The other options support legacy Word documents which don't allow multilevel list!

Answer (score 0):

A summary of what needs to be done.

1.) Select the Range

2.) Configure the ListFormat Property of the Range. Must set DefaultListBehavior
to WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior

3.)Add your Level one text.

4.)Add a paragraph

5.)Add your level two text.

6.)Set ListLevelTier to level 2

```
      public void GenerateMultiLevelList()
    {
        //A Range to write Text
        Word.Range writRange = ActiveDoc.Range(0); 
        writRange.Text = "Tier 1 Bullet Text";

        //Moving the Range to the End of Previously Entered Text
        writRange = ActiveDoc.Range(writRange.End - 1);

        //Formating the Range as a Bullet Point List
        writRange.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(BulletListTemplate, true, Word.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList, Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior);

        //Adding a Paragraph
        writRange.Paragraphs.Add();
        writRange = ActiveDoc.Range(writRange.End - 1);
        writRange.Text = "Tier 2 Bullet Text";

        //Setting the List Level to 2 
        writRange.SetListLevel(2);
    }
```

[image]